# PHP nested loop Bug

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, nested

i have developed the following code to find out all armstrong numbers between 100 and 1000, but for some reason is not behaving as expected.

```
for($i=99;$i<1000;$i++){
    $x = str_split($i);
    $arm = 0;
    foreach ($x as $n){
        $arm = $arm + pow($n,3);
        if ($arm == $i){
            echo $i."\n";
        }
     }
 }
```

The code checks the value of $i against the value of $arm, if it match, it prints $i. Meaning that $i is a armstrong number. the output is the following.

```
153
370
370
371
407
```

For some reason is printing twice 370, but according to the first loop $i will hold only once the value of 370. So why im i getting twice 370???

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because at `370` you do: `3^3 + 7^3` which already is equal to `370` and you print the number out in your foreach loop. But adding `0^3` to `370` in the next and last iteration still is equal to `370` and you output the number again.

Comment: Yep. Basically you need to move the `if` to _after_ the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 370 twice because:

```
33 + 73 == 33 + 73 + 03  //27 + 343  == 27 + 343 + 0
```

Try to put the if statement *after* the foreach loop when you have added everything together:

```
for($i = 99; $i < 1000; $i++){

    $x = str_split($i);
    $arm = 0;

    foreach ($x as $n){
        $arm = $arm + pow($n, 3);
    }

    if ($arm == $i){
        echo $i . "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rizier123 for adding your contributions to my answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't just say to OP to "try something". Always explain why you changed something in OP's code.